# Codeigniter redirecting instead of printing errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter is suddenly redirecting all of my pages to a page generated by error_php.php. I have turned all error reporting on in php.ini along with putting the site in development mode in index.php but it still won't print out the actual php error that causes the redirect. How can I get codeigniter to not redirect me to error_php but rather print the errors?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://thecancerus.com/how-to-catch-php-fatal-error-in-codeigniter/) might help you. Also you might want to set the error reporting option value on your `application/config/config.php` file. Open up the file and go to line #183, change the 
`$config['log_threshold']` value to whatever you like.

```
0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
2 = Debug Messages
3 = Informational Messages
4 = All Messages
```

You might also wanna check out this [link](http://thecancerus.com/how-to-catch-php-fatal-error-in-codeigniter/).